# Installing XMPP on a Python server

Tags: python, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I am attempting to follow set up the python xmpp server for GCM as detailed here:

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html

The website I used for hosting is pythonanywhere.com

My issue is that when I saw `import xmpp`, it says that no such module is found.

Should I be trying to install it on their server? I realize that this issue is probably really basic, but I have looked online for the last hour or so without much fruit. I see all these variations on XMPP and am not sure if I have to deal with any of those or if I can just do exactly what the google demo is saying.

Thanks for your time,

-Alper

Answer (score 2):

PythonAnywhere doesn't support raw TCP socket connections or websockets, so XMPP may not work. But then again, from reading wikipedia, it does look like there's a pure-HTTP alternative, so it *might* work.

Check out this guide to installing new modules:  https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/InstallingNewModules.  My suggestion would be to use a [virtualenv](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/Virtualenvs) for your web app, and install flask and xmpp into that...

Answer (score 1):

You will have to download and install the missing python package. You may do this manually via SSH if the provider gives you access, or there may be a way to include a requirements document such that the server looks and downloads needed packages automatically. It all depends on the host, the access they allow you, and their automation features.